# The mice package/function in R is throwing an lm.fit error I don't understand

Tags: r, lm, imputation, r-mice

I'm trying to use the mice package to impute on a large dataset. There are 14 variables with missing values, which I need the mice() function to impute, but when I try to use the function, it keeps throwing the same error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x = x, y = y) : 'x' must be a matrix
```

Every value in my data is numeric, and I'm getting no errors from the function itself telling me I have a bad input. I have no idea what's causing this error. I assume I'm misunderstanding something about the predictorMatrix or the blocks.

Below is the function call and the construction of the blocks and the predictorMatrix:

```
b <- make.blocks(c("CountHU","HH","D1A","D1C8_OFF","D4A","D4C","D4D","D4E","D5BR","D5BE","D5DR","D5DRI","D5DE","D5DEI"))
pm <- matrix(0, nrow = length(b), ncol = ncol(df))
pm[1,c(24,28)] <- 1 #AutoOwn1, Workers predict CountHU
pm[2,c(18,24,28)] <- 1 #TotPop, AutoOwn1, Workers predict HH
pm[3,c(23,52)] <- 1 #D1B, Pct_AO0 predict D1A
pm[4,c(40,62)] <- 1 #E8_off, D1C8_SVC predict D1C8_OFF
pm[5,c(23,27,82)] <- 1 #Pct_AO0, Pct_AO2p, D3A predict D4A
pm[6,c(27,94,95)] <- 1 #Pct_AO2p, D4B025, D4B050 predict D4C
pm[7,c(23,52,93)] <- 1 #Pct_AO0, D1B, D4B025 predict D4D
pm[8,c(93,94)] <- 1 #D4B025, D4B050 predict D4E (badly)
pm[9,c(86,98,99)] <-1 #D3B, D5AR, D5AE predict D5BR
pm[10,c(98,99)] <- 1 #D5AR, D5AE predict D5BE
pm[11,c(102,104)] <- 1 #D5CR, D5CE predict D5DR
pm[12,c(103,105)] <- 1 #D5CRI, D5CEI predict D5DRI
pm[13,c(102,104)] <- 1 #D5CR, D5CE predict D5DE
pm[14,c(103,105)] <- 1 #D5CRI, D5CEI predict D5DEI
df_imputed_all <- mice(data = df, method = "norm.boot", predictorMatrix = pm, blocks = b)
```

Edit: below are a few lines from the dataframe df

```
> df
   GEOID10  GEOID20 STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE BLKGRPCE CSA CSA_Name  CBSA
1 4.81e+11 4.81e+11      48      113    7825        4 206   -99999 19100
2 4.81e+11 4.81e+11      48      113    7825        2 206   -99999 19100
3 4.81e+11 4.81e+11      48      113    7825        3 206   -99999 19100
4 4.81e+11 4.81e+11      48      113    7824        1 206   -99999 19100
  CBSA_Name CBSA_POP CBSA_EMP CBSA_WRK  Ac_Total Ac_Water   Ac_Land   Ac_Unpr
1    -99999  7189384  3545715  3364458  73.59503        0  73.59503  73.59503
2    -99999  7189384  3545715  3364458 119.82991        0 119.82991 119.21420
3    -99999  7189384  3545715  3364458  26.36705        0  26.36705  26.36705
4    -99999  7189384  3545715  3364458 119.06069        0 119.06069 119.06069
```

Every -99999 element was a string which I replaced with an integer.

Comment: You should share `dput` of your `df`